# WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM).',)

Tags: python, redis, celery

I recently started using celery in a new Django project. Settings:

```
 -------------- celery@123 v3.1.7 (Cipater) 
---- **** -----  
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.8.11-ec2-x86_64-with-debian-squeeze-sid 
-- * - **** ---  
- ** ---------- [config] 
- ** ---------- .> app:         nextlanding_api:0x1c23250 
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://rediscloud@123123 
- ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend 
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork) 
-- ******* ----  
--- ***** ----- [queues] 
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery 

software -> celery:3.1.7 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.8 py:2.7.4
            billiard:3.3.0.13 redis:2.9.0
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:redis results:djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
```

I'm investigating an issue where tasks with eta 24+ hours are *disappearing* (I've ensured the [visibility_timeout](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.celeryproject.org%2Fen%2Flatest%2Fgetting-started%2Fbrokers%2Fredis.html%23visibility-timeout&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEzmB6ksRrOi4OwE5pyNfO9SH3O6w) is > 24 hours). When I warmly shut down the worker, the log statements show several messages being acknowledged. Example:
`Restoring 26 unacknowledged message(s).`

However, I expected ~50 or so unacknowledged messages to be restored. Looking into my logs a little closer, I see:

```
[ERROR] celery.worker.job: Task myproj_task[xxx] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM).',)
...
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM). 
Restoring 26 unacknowledged message(s). 
Process exited with status 0
```

I've seen others report OOM kills their process. I am on Heroku and see no [R14](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdevcenter.heroku.com%2Farticles%2Ferror-codes%23r14-memory-quota-exceeded&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFeBZ2Q6kn_OX9YtudNjf_c4oUeVA) codes.

One last bit of context, I'm spawning new processes from within my tasks.

My question is: is the WorkerLostError something I should worry about? The status code is 15 (SIGTERM) which seems to be OK. If this error is not normal, could it be a possible cause to losing ETA tasks?

**Edit**

At first I thought items were *disappearing* but after putting in some verbose logs, I can see the tasks were issued but never persisted in redis:

`myproj_email_task was sent. task_id: b6ce2b97-d5b8-4850-9e43-9185426cd9f6`

However, looking over the tasks in redis, the task `b6ce2b97-d5b8-4850-9e43-9185426cd9f6` does not exist.

So it would appear the tasks are not disappearing, but either not being sent at all or not being put into the `unacked` redis key.

Comment: Have the same issues with 'normal' tasks not eta or countdown. Worker just dies, plenty of memory left. Did you find out what caused it for you?

Comment: I moved away from celery but I think the issue had to do with using the database as a faux message queue. Once I moved to redis or rabbitmq, I think this probelm resolved itself.

Comment: You are just using plain redis/rabbitmq now? But you are still using Python?

Answer (score 4):

The cause of these WorkerLostErrors is quite likely an incompatibility between the behaviors of Celery and Heroku:

- A Celery worker expects a SIGTERM on the parent worker process, in which case it lets its subprocesses finish their current tasks.
- When doing a 'warm shutdown' of a dyno, Heroku sends a SIGTERM to all processes in the dyno.

Therefore, all the worker subprocesses get the SIGTERM as well and start immediately terminating, resulting in the WorkerLostErrors.

A workaround has been prepared for the unreleased Celery 4.0: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2839

I haven't found a solution for 3.1.19 yet.

Answer (score 1):

WorkerLostError is not normal, and you should definitely be concerned.

As for ack/restarts on long running jobs: Celery does its very best, but if you're paranoid and you're expecting a guaranteed delivery/execution/ack model even when the parent/worker die under unusual circumstances, you might consider using a secondary data store to track progress and metadata, so that you have fine-grain control:

```
Client->TransactionalDB: insert JOB
Client->Celery: send_async(job_id)
Celery->Worker: do(job_id)
Worker->TransactionalDB: update started job + meta
...
Worker->TransactionalDB: update progress + meta
...
?->Worker: die!
...
Celerybeat->Worker: checkForOrphans()
Worker->TransactionalDB: select where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

WorkerLost on `SIGTERM` is definitely not normal. How is it possible to restart a process without losing tasks in such case? Even `ack_late` option doesn't help.

I think the wish to do not lose tasks on `SIGTERM` is far from paranoidal.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today. I have a task which  spawns subprocesses and execution was randomly interrupted with

> WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM).

Finally I've found that the cause of it was here:
I used multiprocessing.Pool to spawn new processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(2)
data = pool.map( some_func, some_data) 
pool.terminate()
```

It seems that pool.terminate() sometimes sends SIGTERM not only to spawned processes but to itself too. 
When I've changed pool.terminate() to:

```
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

everything became OK.

Comment: I guess you meant in the opposite order: first ```pool.close()``` and THEN ```pool.join()```.